# Has tf.Estimator become obsolete in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Today I've set up a custom model using its tf.Estimator high-level API in Tensorflow 2.0.
It was a pain in the *** to get it running, and there are very few complete examples online that implement custom Estimators in Tensorflow 2, which made me questioning the reasons for using this API.

According to the docs, the main advantages of using the tf.Estimator API are:

1. You can run Estimator-based models on a local host or on a distributed multi-server environment without changing your model. Furthermore, you can run Estimator-based models on CPUs, GPUs, or TPUs without recoding your model.
2. You no longer have to worry about creating the computational graph or sessions since Estimators handle all the "plumbing" for you

Advantage 2. clearly doesn't apply to Tensorflow 2.0 anymore, as it runs in eager mode by default, so you don't have to worry about sessions anyways.

Advantage 1. also seems quite irrelevant in Tensorflow 2.0 - using tf.distribute.Strategy, you can now easily run even high level tf.Keras models in a distributed fashion and on CPUs/GPUs/TPUs.
tf.Keras models are so much easier and faster to set up, so why did they even bother to keep the tf.Estimator API in Tensorflow 2.0? Are there other advantages of using this API?

Comment: Yes, your observations are correct. In `Tensorflow 2.x`, most of the functionalities work effectively with `High Level APIs of Keras`.